# How to rewrite the input data (range) of a function with a new variable (variant)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to give new value to input data in my function: let data (range) be data2 (variant). How can I achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
Function test(data As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim data2() As Variant

ReDim data2(data.Columns.Count * 4)

For i = 1 To (4 * data.Columns.Count)
data2(1 + (i - 1) * 4, 1) = 0
data2(2 + (i - 1) * 4, 1) = 0
data2(3 + (i - 1) * 4, 1) = 0
data2(4 + (i - 1) * 4, 1) = data(i)
Next i

data = data2 'this is where it fails
' ...
'50 rows of code
' ...
```

test
        End Function

This is *data*:

[image]

I define *data2* = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,3]. Then, I'd like to give new values to *data*:

*data* = *data2*

(I don't want to input these *data2* values, I just need *data2* for my calculations.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You are giving a range(single cell or selection of cells), what is your desired output? a calculation? the output should be `Test = data` but `Test` isn't a `Variant` so I guess it's not gonna give what you need either.

Comment: I'd like to rewite values of data with the values of data2. This is just the first part of the code, but it fails at the seventh row.

Comment: do you really need a function to that? you can use a procedure.

Comment: Yes, it will be a Hodrick-Prescott filtering function.

Comment: Try the answer I posted if it helps you. You don't need a separate array to later match on your range, you can just work the range.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are meant to give you something back, a value, string or whatever. When you are modifying something from another procedure just use a Sub:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test(data As Range)

    Dim C As Range

     For Each C In data
        C = 1
     Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just updated my question to make my question clear.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following data

[image]

And the following test function calling your procedure `MyProcedure`.

```
Option Explicit    

Public Sub test()
    MyProcedure Range("A1:C1")
End Sub
```

The thing is, that a range **always** consists of `rows` and `columns` even if you only have one row like `Range("A1:J1")` your array `NewData` needs to reflect that by it's dimensions `NewData(rows, columns)`.

```
Public Sub MyProcedure(ByRef InputData As Range)
    Dim NewData() As Variant
    ReDim NewData(1 To InputData.Rows.Count, 1 To InputData.Columns.Count * 4)

    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 To InputData.Columns.Count * 4
        If iCol Mod 4 = 0 Then
            NewData(1, iCol) = InputData(1, iCol / 4)
        Else
            NewData(1, iCol) = 0
        End If
    Next iCol

    'InputData data needs to be resized otherwise it cannot take all data from NewData!
    InputData.Resize(ColumnSize:=InputData.Columns.Count * 4).Value = NewData
End Sub
```

The result will be:

[image]

I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Thank you! I've just updated my question, I wasn't quite clear about the problem.

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar Then `InputData` has to be resized to take all the `NewData`. You cannot put 12 cells into a range of 3 cells. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks.  InputData.Resize(ColumnSize:=InputData.Columns.Count * 4).Value = NewData this one does'nt work for me :(

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar Test it exactly as described above with the example data described above. It works (I tested the code). • Aso note that *"doesn't work for me"* is an error description that is completely meaningless and useless to help you. • Try to use exactly the code I posted on exactly the shown example data and it will work. After that slowly try to change it to your needs.